# program freezes when listening for client through sockets

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, client-server

I'm trying to make a server socket to listen to a client input stream but when i execute the `start_listening()` method, my program gets stuck. I even tried to remove the loop, but i still have the same problem. i guess that it waits for the client interaction. is there an alternative way to listen while the program is also working?

```
public static void start_listening(){

listener = new ServerSocket(9090);

while (true) {          
Socket socket = listener.accept();      
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
us = (User) in.readObject();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the sockets technique, `accept()` blocks the execution of the current thread until a client connects to the listening socket. This is a defined behavior. [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29) says: "The method [`accept()`] blocks until a connection is made." Have the server run within a endless loop can be ok.

So, to get this whole thing run you might want to take a look at [this socket example which uses threads](http://www.kodejava.org/how-do-i-create-a-client-server-socket-communication/). Inside the `run()` method of `ConnectionHandler` you would deal with your User object.

Answer (score 1):

Besides that the loop never ends (I suppose you will break at some point), you should do that kind of stuff in a separate [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#) or an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), doing accept in the main thread makes Andriod freeze until somebody connects to the socket. That's why your program gets stuck.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try to find a way to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

You might just use a `Boolean` `flag` to indicate when to end the while loop.Other wise the loop keep iteration as it never breaks.

```
while (true) {    //will it ever breaks ??

}
```

Comment: i deleted the loop, it still get's stuck